# How to test Grails validation on non-domain classes

Tags: validation, grails

We put validation on a non-domain class, which works fine when the app is run.  However, we would like to unit test the validation, but the test seems to be ignoring the constraints block and using only default validation constraints.

Here's our production class:

```
import grails.validation.Validateable

@Validateable
class TransactToken {

    String institutionId
    String username
    boolean expired = false
    //optional fields
    String email
    String customCssUrl
    String roleName = Role.CARDHOLDER

    static constraints = {
        institutionId blank: false
        username blank: false
        expired notEqual: true
        email email: true, nullable: true
        customCssUrl url: true, nullable: true
        roleName inList: [ Role.DIRECTOR, Role.OFFICE, Role.CARDHOLDER]
    }

}
```

And our test class:

```
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class TransactTokenSpec extends Specification {

    @Unroll
    void "test isValid (institutionId: #institutionId, username: #username, expired: #expired, roleName: #roleName)"() {
        given: "A token with the provided params"
        TransactToken transactToken = new TransactToken(
                institutionId: institutionId,
                username: username,
                expired: expired,
                roleName: roleName,
                email: "bacon@eggs.edu",
                customCssUrl: "http://bacon.edu"
        )

        when:
        transactToken.validate()
        if (transactToken.hasErrors()) {println transactToken.errors}

        then:
        valid != transactToken.hasErrors()

        where:
        institutionId | username | expired | roleName        || valid
        'asdf'        | 'asdf'   | false   | Role.CARDHOLDER || true
        'asdf'        | ''       | false   | Role.CARDHOLDER || false
        'asdf'        | 'asdf'   | false   | Role.CARDHOLDER || true
        ''            | 'asdf'   | false   | Role.CARDHOLDER || false
        'asdf'        | ''       | false   | Role.CARDHOLDER || false
        'asdf'        | 'asdf'   | true    | Role.CARDHOLDER || false
        'asdf'        | 'asdf'   | false   | Role.OFFICE     || true
        'asdf'        | 'asdf'   | false   | Role.DIRECTOR   || true
        'asdf'        | 'asdf'   | false   | Role.ADMIN      || false

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is a bit of a hack, but we figured this out.

I think the problem is that we needed the @TestFor annotation, which I doesn't seem to work for a non-grails classes.

The service that depends on this classes validation and that uses the @TestFor annotation, so we moved this test there, and it worked as expected.

```
@TestFor(TransactTokenService)
@ConfineMetaClassChanges(Organization)
class TransactTokenServiceSpec extends Specification {

    @Unroll
    void "test #label: valid should be #valid."() {
        given: "A token with the provided params"
        TransactToken transactToken = new TransactToken(
                institutionId: institutionId,
                username: username,
                expired: expired,
                roleName: roleName,
                customCssUrl: url,
                email: email
        )

        when:
        transactToken.validate()

        then:
        valid != transactToken.hasErrors()

        where:
        institutionId | username | expired | roleName        | email              | url                  || valid || label
        'asdf'        | 'asdf'   | false   | Role.CARDHOLDER | "bacon@sharptop.co"| "http://sharptop.co" || true  || "all valid"
        'asdf'        | ''       | false   | Role.CARDHOLDER | ""                 | ""                   || false || "blank username"
        'asdf'        | 'asdf'   | false   | Role.CARDHOLDER | ""                 | ""                   || true  || "blank email and url"
        ''            | 'asdf'   | false   | Role.CARDHOLDER | ""                 | ""                   || false || "blank institution id"
        'asdf'        | 'asdf'   | true    | Role.CARDHOLDER | ""                 | ""                   || false || "expired token"
        'asdf'        | 'asdf'   | false   | Role.OFFICE     | ""                 | ""                   || true  || "valid office user"
        'asdf'        | 'asdf'   | false   | Role.DIRECTOR   | ""                 | ""                   || true  || "valid director user"
        'asdf'        | 'asdf'   | false   | Role.ADMIN      | ""                 | ""                   || false || "invalid admin user"
        'asdf'        | 'asdf'   | false   | Role.CARDHOLDER | "bacon@sharptop.co"| "bacon"              || false || "invalid url"
        'asdf'        | 'asdf'   | false   | Role.CARDHOLDER | "bacon"            | "http://sharptop.co" || false || "invalid email"
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `@TestFor(TransactTokenService)` is a little peculiar here since the test doesn't appear to have anything to do with the service.  I think a better idea is to mark the test with `@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)`.  We include an example of that in the user guide at http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.9/guide/testing.html#unitTesting (search for "MyValidateableSpec" on that page).

Answer (score 0):

FYI for anyone reading this for Grails 3 or 4. Validateable is an interface instead of an Annotation now. You implement it like this on a class:

```
import grails.validation.Validateable

class UserRow implements Validateable {
    ...
}
```